# Firebase chat adds message in other conversation when online

Tags: android, ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We have implemented a chat application both in iOS and Android which is 1:1 chat, and the structure is also well designed. Recently we figured out a bug which sends message to another user when they are online. Refer the eg

Suppose there are 3 People, User - A, User - B and User - C

User - B sends a message to User - A
User - C sends a message to User - A

Now, User A is in conversation with User - B and User - C sends a message to User - A that message comes in User - A and User - B Chat....

First we thought it was a bug on the iOS side and later on we tested the same with Android and it behaves the same way.

Below is the Firebase Structure

[image: Chat Structure]

So it is like

- Chat

  - USER-A-ID-USER-B-ID

    - RandomID

      - Chat Data

Below is the code for Reference

```
let childRef = Database.database().reference().child("chat").child(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"UserId")!+"-"+UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"receiverUserId")!)
let childRef1 = Database.database().reference().child("chat").child(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"receiverUserId")!+"-"+UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"UserId")!)

let key = childRef.childByAutoId().key
let date = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(abbreviation: "UTC")
let result = formatter.string(from: date)
let message = ["sender_id":UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"uid")!,"receiver_id":UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"receiverUID")!,"sender_name":UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"UserName")!,"text":text,"timestamp":result,"status":"0","time":"","type":"text","pic_url":"","chat_id":key]
childRef.child(key!).setValue(message)
childRef1.child(key!).setValue(message)
```

Here's the code which is observing the change in the database

```
 func setUpChats() {
//Sender
    let channelSender = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"uid")! + "-" + UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"receiverUID")!
    let childRefSender = Database.database().reference().child("chat").child(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"uid")!+"-"+UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"receiverUID")!).queryOrdered(byChild: channelSender).queryLimited(toLast:self.start_index)
    childRefSender.keepSynced(true)
    childRefSender.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
            self.timearray = []
            self.seenTime = []
            self.seenStatus = []
            self.messages = []
            self.chat_ids = []
            self.urls = []
            for artists in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                let artistObject = artists.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                print("artistObject:", artistObject!)
                let key1 = artists.key
                print("Key1:",key1) //other user channel id

                let id          = artistObject!["sender_id"]
                let rece_id          = artistObject!["receiver_id"] as! String
                let chat_id          = artistObject!["chat_id"] as! String
                let name        = artistObject!["sender_name"]
                let text        = artistObject!["text"] as! String
                let time        = artistObject!["timestamp"]
                let status        = artistObject!["status"] as! String
                let seenTime        = artistObject!["time"] as! String
                let type        = artistObject!["type"] as! String
                let imgurl        = artistObject!["pic_url"] as! String
                if(type == "image") {
                    let imageView = AsyncPhotoMediaItem(withURL: URL(string: imgurl)!)
                    if id as? String == self.senderId {
                        imageView.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = true
                    }
                    else {
                        imageView.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = false
                    }
                    let message = JSQMessage(senderId:id as? String, displayName: name as? String, media: imageView)

                    self.messages.add(message!)
                } else if(type == "text") {
                let message = JSQMessage(senderId: id as? String , displayName: name as? String , text: text )
                    print("Mesage:",message!)
                self.messages.add(message!)
                }
                print("Time:", time!)
                let localTime = self.utcToLocal(dateStr: time as! String)
                print("localTime:", localTime!)
                
                self.timearray.add(localTime!)
                self.seenTime.add(seenTime)
                self.seenStatus.add(status)
                self.type.add(type)
                self.chat_ids.add(chat_id)
                self.urls.add(imgurl)
                if(self.senderId != id as? String ){
                    if(status == "0"){
                        let statusUpdateRef = Database.database().reference().child("chat").child(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"uid")!+"-"+UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"receiverUID")!)

                        let date = Date()
                        let formatter = DateFormatter()
                        formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
                        let result = formatter.string(from: date)
                        let fullNameArr = result.components(separatedBy: " ")

                        // let name    = fullNameArr[0]
                        let surname = fullNameArr[1]
                        let dateFormatter1 = DateFormatter()
                        dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
                        let date1 = dateFormatter1.date(from:surname)
                        dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
                        let starting_time = dateFormatter1.string(from:date1!)

                        let message = ["sender_id":id as! String,"receiver_id":rece_id,"sender_name":name!,"text":text,"timestamp":time!,"status":"1","time":starting_time,"type":type,"pic_url":imgurl,"chat_id":chat_id] as [String : Any]
                        statusUpdateRef.child(key1).updateChildValues(message)
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)
                    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
                    self.collectionView.hideActivityIndicator()
                     self.finishReceivingMessage()
                }
            }
        } else {
            self.collectionView.showActivityIndicator()
        }
    })

    //Receiver
    let channel1 = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"receiverUID")! + "-" + UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"uid")!

    let childRefReceiver = Database.database().reference().child("chat").child(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"receiverUID")!+"-"+UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"uid")!).queryOrdered(byChild: channel1).queryLimited(toLast:self.start_index)
    childRefReceiver.keepSynced(true)
    childRefReceiver.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
            for artists in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                let artistObject = artists.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let key1 = artists.key
                print(key1)
                let id          = artistObject!["sender_id"]
                let rece_id          = artistObject!["receiver_id"] as! String
                let chat_id          = artistObject!["chat_id"] as! String
                let name        = artistObject!["sender_name"]
                let text        = artistObject!["text"]
                let time        = artistObject!["timestamp"]
                let status        = artistObject!["status"] as! String
                let imgurl        = artistObject!["pic_url"] as! String
                let type        = artistObject!["type"] as! String

                if(self.senderId != id as? String ){
                    if(status == "0"){
                        let childRefUpdate = Database.database().reference().child("chat").child(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"receiverUID")!+"-"+UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"uid")!)
                        let date = Date()
                        let formatter = DateFormatter()
                        formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
                        let result = formatter.string(from: date)
                        let fullNameArr = result.components(separatedBy: " ")
                        let surname = fullNameArr[1]
                        let dateFormatter1 = DateFormatter()
                        dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
                        let date1 = dateFormatter1.date(from:surname)
                        dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
                        let starting_time = dateFormatter1.string(from:date1!)

                        let message = ["sender_id":id as! String,"receiver_id":rece_id,"sender_name":name!,"text":text!,"timestamp":time!,"status":"1","time":starting_time,"type":type,"pic_url":imgurl,"chat_id":chat_id] as [String : Any]
                        childRefUpdate.child(key1).updateChildValues(message)
                    }
                }
      }
```

Please help me out where I am going wrong or what I need to change in the structure.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have edited my question and have added the code snippet how I am storing the messages.

Comment: You're storing the exact same message in both the chat from user A to user C as from user C to user A? Meaning the receiver_id and sender_id will be the same in both messages? Sounds like a logic issue as I would think they would not be the same.

Comment: @Jay The message node is inside the main node of chat, and storing of data in that message node should not affect the main node where I am showing the path to store the data

Comment: We don't know what `main node` and `message node` means in relation to your  structure. The `message` is stored in both nodes shown in the code `receiveUserId` and `UserId` and it's not clear why that's being done. Also, we don't know what: - *that message comes in User - A and User - B Chat....* - means. How does that message comes in those chats? Is there an observer in your code that's firing when a new message is posted or are you using some other method to know when that occurs? Help us to help you my clarifying the question as we are not seeing a problem with the code in the question.

Comment: @Jay The message is stored in 2 nodes i.e. 1 for User A and Other for User B, so if the user A tries to delete the message for him, it'll deleted from his node and not from User B. Hence storing in 2 nodes.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't appear to be related to the question itself. In other words, if User-A is conversing with User-B and User-A is also conversing with User-C, and User-C sends a new message to User-A, and that messages "comes up" in User-A and User-B conversation, that code is unrelated to what ever "comes up" means. We don't know how you're getting/observing/listening to messages but that code doesn't do that task; it just writes data.

Comment: @Jay I have updated my question with the code for setting up chats which is showing messages in receiver and sender when sent

Comment: That's quite a bit of unrelated code for us to parse through but I would guess that either a) the data is being written to the wrong node and/or b) you're observer is not set up correctly and notifying the app of events it's not interested in. I say that because any time `.value` is used, if there are changes to *anything* in the observed node, all of the data in the node is passed to the app. It's generally better to observe `.childAdded`, `.childChanged` and `.childRemoved` events as it's a much more granular observe (and less data). Maybe if you can reduce the code, we will spot something.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to say what's going wrong here without seeing the exact flow, but it sounds like you may not be updating `UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"UserId")` when the signed in user changes, so be sure to use an auth state listener for that as shown in the first code snippet in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

It may also be that you're not be updating `UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"receiverUserId")` when the user selects another recipient, so be sure to check that too.

Comment: I have done the debugging of the whole code on how the messages are stored when the send message button is pressed, I can see in the console that only 2 nodes are created i.e. 1-5 and 5-1. Initially I made the node like senderUID-receiverUID, and then changed to single UserID which is also giving the same problem. In the console it prints 2 nodes where the message is being stored but in firebase it is storing in all the nodes who are in conversation with that user and are online. That's really weird and I am not able to track the issue, hence posted the question here for the help.

Comment: I have updated my question with the code which observe event change. Please help